# Query string and outlook email for local file path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, outlook

I have a problem with a query string in Outlook: I have a file path where the query string is attached in an Outlook email. If the hyperlink in Outlook is clicked, the query string parameter is getting removed for some reason. For example, if I click the following hyperlink in Outlook

```
file://path/form1.html?querystring=value
```

the link that actually gets opened is

```
file://path/form1.html
```

As you can see, the query string was removed, basically everything after the `?`.

I tried it with `#` but it is the same.

Comment: I am using outlook 2010. If the url is in http format with query string, it is working without any issue. I am able to open the hyperlink from outlook with query string. But the problem happens only if the url format is  file://path with query string.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of possible issues that may cause this behavior:

- there is an issue with the encoding that leads to a malformed URL. Check the email content encoding in your Outlook the settings (file, options, advanced -encoding option, I believe).
- Office/Outlook checks whether a linked URL address is correct (to download and open it) and drops the query string since it cannot handle it. I have seen related [Registry settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/218153/error-message-when-clicking-hyperlink-in-office-cannot-locate-the-inte) that change this behavior (adjust according to your Office version):

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
  Office\14.0\Common\Internet\ForceShellExecute:DWORD=1
  ```
- Office/Outlook security prevents what you are trying to do for a local file:// paths. (Maybe this helps here too: [How to disable hyperlink warning messages in 2007 and Office 2010 programs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/925757/how-to-enable-or-disable-hyperlink-warning-messages-in-2007-office-pro))
- Your file URI is invalid: See this old but probably still valid [IEBlog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/)

  > Incorrect: file://D:\Program Files\Viewer\startup.htm Correct:
  >   file:///D:/Program%20Files/Viewer/startup.htm
  >
  > Incorrect: C:\Program Files\Music\Web Sys\main.html?REQUEST=RADIO
  >   Correct: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Music/Web%20Sys/main.html?REQUEST=RADIO
  >
  > Incorrect: file:////applib/products/a%2Db/
  >   abc%5F9/4148.920a/media/start.swf Correct:
  >   file://applib/products/a-b/abc_9/4148.920a/media/start.swf

PS: Others had asked the same question on the [microsoft answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_2013_release/query-string-removed-from-hyperlink-in-email/18a37923-4482-4d52-853e-c7bc448a7c6a) without success.